# I followed all of the steps in the sendgrid videos etc. I this error

Tags: dependencies, composer-php, version

Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.2.0". You are running 8.1.27. in /home/turnproa/public_html/AMS/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24

I tried

```
<?php

require ('vendor/autoload.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 2525;
$mail->Username = '1a2c62349d628e';
$mail->Password = '231be3e4c0b3e3';

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('TurnProJason@gmail.com', 'Jason Webber');
$mail->addAddress('sirwebbie@gmail.com', 'webDawg');

$mail->Body= 'this is my email body';
        $mail->AddReplyTo('turnprojason@gmail.com', 'Aqua jason');
        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
        $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
   //     $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
        //$mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
        //$mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
        $mail->Send();
        echo "Message Sent OK\n the body is sent";

?>
```

and I was expecting an email in my inbox

Process.
install composer components following steps on sendgrid
upload my vendor folder from computer to hostGator server
write my file (in dreamwearver) and upload to host gator
refresh website and get error

Comment: Anything unclear about the given error message?